# nested property listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-4

I use EF and set DataSource of bindingSource as User.

now in listBox I would Like to set valueMember asUserId
and DisplayMember as Product.ProductName (nested property)

schemat is:

```
User
_________
UserId
UserName
ProductId


Product
_________
ProductId
ProductName
```

I WOuld like to bind a lot of Users to that control and display ProductNames but now there is visible only one ProductName even though there are for example 4 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes generated by EF are partial, so you can create another source file and add a property to your User class, like that:

```
public partial class User {
    public string ProductName { get { return this.Product.ProductName; } }
}
```

this way you would not need to access nested properties for DisplayMember.